# Upper bound on error function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to show:

$\text{erf}(x) \leq \sqrt{1-\exp{(-\frac{4}{\pi}x^2})}$

I tried applying a chernoff bound, but that doesnt give me a bound in terms of the squareroot.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered here: [Proving $1-\exp(-4x^2/ \pi) \ge \text{erf}(x)^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6908/proving-1-exp-4x2-pi-ge-texterfx2) (eventually found this link from a discussion on twitter)